# How to calculate shape of a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In order to understand a tensor in tensorflow clearly, I need to have a clear understanding of how is the shape a tensor defined.

These are some examples from the tensorflow document:

`3 # a rank 0 tensor; this is a scalar with shape []
[1. ,2., 3.] # a rank 1 tensor; this is a vector with shape [3]
[[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]] # a rank 2 tensor; a matrix with shape [2, 3]
[[[1., 2., 3.]], [[7., 8., 9.]]] # a rank 3 tensor with shape [2, 1, 3]`

Is the below understanding of mine correct:

**In order to find the shape of the tensor, we start from the outermost list and count the number of elements (or lists) inside. This count makes the first dimension. We then repeat this procedure for the inner lists and find the next dimensions of the tensor.**

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. If you have a valid tensor, your algorithm will return you the correct dimensions of the tensor. You can write it in python in the following way

```
def get_shape(arr):
    res = []
    while isinstance((arr), list):
        res.append(len(arr))
        arr = arr[0]
    return res
```

Notice that in case of the arbitrary value of arr, you also need to make sure that dimensions match (`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]` is not a valid tensor)